# Change role color

Tags: python, discord

I'm new in discord api and I want to make a bot for discord. I want to make a command that changes role's color.
I use this code to change color:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_message(self, message):
        server = client.get_guild('')
        for role in server.roles:
            if role.name == 'Цвет':
                await client.edit_role(server=server, role=role, colour=0x0080000)
                break
```

I got 2 errors:

```
Instance of 'MyClient' has no 'edit_role' member

File ".\mybot.py", line 10, in on_message
    for role in server.roles:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at an outdated API documentation, see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=edit_role

`Client.edit_role()` was used before v1.0. You need an instance of class Role and do `Role.edit()`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role.edit

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    server = client.get_guild('')
    for role in server.roles:
        if role.name == 'Цвет':
            await role.edit(color=0x080000)
```

Comment: Can you make an example for Role.edit please? I do not understand :/

Comment: I tried that: await discord.Role.edit(name='Цвет', server=server, self=None, role=role, colour=0x0080000). But it didn't work and there are no errors.